# OpenSSL cookie support

Tags: openssl

I have a basic (HTTP over) SSL client written using the OpenSSL library, following the exact instructions provided in  the "Network Security with OpenSSL" book (Chandra, Messier, Viega).
The client is NOT a part of a web browser (it's a dedicated client-server application).

The server I'm working with (not under my control) will soon start using cookies for identifying client requests, so I've searched "Network Security with OpenSSL" and some websites for how to add cookie support to my OpenSSL client. No luck. The only info I can find is how to add cookie support to an OpenSSL based SERVER, which is not what I need.

Any good references you can give me?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Cookies are not related to SSL in any way. They are part of HTTP protocol and are described in [RFC 2965](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2965.txt).

Upd: our developers suggested that maybe you were looking for information on renegotiation security issue, where to workaround it cookie-like mechanism was used, but this is unlikely. You better ask your server admin for additional information.

Comment: The OpenSSL library wraps the TCP layer, and as such is supposed to offer (so I've been told) cookies handling. You can imagine that if it didn't it would be rather pointless to use it, since I can't simply add cookie support in the modules managing the sending and receiving of HTTP messages and disregard the OpenSSL layer. How will I exactly make the cookie SSL-compatible? There must be something I just can't find the right documentation.

Comment: @user181218 OpenSSL wraps TCP layer, but not HTTP afaik. In your code, who creates HTTP request and parses HTTP response? Is it OpenSSL or your own code?

Comment: OpenSSL does this. If it were my code there would be no question about who's responsible for adding cookie support. EVERYTHING is done by the openSSL functions.

Comment: @user181218 which exactly sample from the book are you using? I've downloaded the source code that accompanies the book and I'd like to see that HTTP code that you are following.

Comment: @user181218: This answer is correct.  Cookies are part of HTTP, and are unrelated to SSL.  Cookies do not need to be "SSL-compatible" any more than the rest of your application-layer protocol.  Perhaps you are looking for client certificates instead? Those can be used to authenticate clients, and *are* part of SSL.